# MySQL Query Order by before Group By

Tags: mysql

```
name    order_id
tom |       1    |
tom |       0    |
tom |       2    |
tom |       3    |
tom |       4    | 
ken |       2    | 
ken |       1    | 
ken |       0    |
```

I have a table like above, how can I select the data group by the name and order by the order id. I already try the query below but it's not the result I want.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_dummy GROUP BY name ORDER BY order_id ASC
```

Comment: Grouping by the `name` implies doing some sort of aggregation of the `order_id`.  What do you want to do here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to select only two data which are tom with order id 0  and ken with order id 0

Comment: You are not using aggregation function .. so why you are using group by ?  .. in this case the gupo by work as an order by too

Comment: select * from my_table whete order_id=0;

Comment: Yeah, just strikeout the GROUP BY. So it remains: `SELECT * FROM tbl_dummy ORDER BY order_id ASC`

Comment: Do you want to select zero because it is the lowest value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yup I want it to be ordered from lowest to highest

Comment: @Muli But I only need two data which are tom with order id 0 and ken with order id 0

Comment: This still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What doesn't make sense?

Comment: Do you want to select zero because it is the lowest value, or something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yup I want to select it because it is the lowest

Answer (score 1):

This *might* be what you want:

```
SELECT name, MIN(order_id) AS order_id
FROM tbl_dummy
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

For using `GROUP BY` clause, you must use some type of aggregate function (`SUM, MIN, MAX ..`) on all the other columns that you are selecting.
Try understand it this way, if you do group by name in the above data, then you will have two rows in the result, one for tom and one for ken. But what value of `order_id` should it display against each name? It cannot display all the values separated by comma (or anything else like that). The value to be shown must be a value calculated using all the values corresponding to that name. It could either be sum, average, min or max of all the values.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

May be what you are looking for is to order your results by name first and then order_id in increasing order. In that case you can use **order by multiple columns**

`SELECT name, order_id from yourtable order by name, order_id;`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_dummy GROUP by name,order_id order by name,order_id
```